# Dotnet core React SPA Static Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, single-page-application

I am currently using the dotnet core react Spa solution, I have a need to store and host static content like images and pdf files.

How do I host static content in the dotnet core react SPA solution? preferably like the traditional *wwwroot* way.

The application is already configured for static content.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

I have tried creating a contents folder but I cant acceess the image files from the browser.

[image]

Comment: I believe default behavior is to bundle static content out of the `public` folder, trying moving your content there.

Comment: @JSteward how would get the url for them?

Comment: relative to anywhere in the client would just be `'./images/Genericbanner1.jpg'`